# The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter

i have problem in the panels of covid 19 data.to retrieve if someone have the code so please guide me.

countryData == null ? Container() : MostAffectedPanel( countryData: countryData ),

how i can solve this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1eV8.png

Answer (score 0):

try
countryData == null ? Container() : MostAffectedPanel(key:key, countryData: countryData ),

or make that key nullable in MostAffectedPanel constructor
Eg: Key? key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need add key parameter

```
countryData == null ? 
Container() : MostAffectedPanel( key: UniqueKey(), countryData: countryData ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some changes in the constructor of your `MostAffectedPanel` class,

`MostAffectedPanel({Key? key, required List<dynamic> countryData});`

This is going to make the `Key` parameter nullable and your existing code will work just fine!